# Modular Arithmetic: $ 291-118 \pmod 4\;$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

How do you work out: the value of $ 291-118 \pmod 4\;$?

Thanks

Comment: It identically equals `(291 mod 4) - (118 mod 4).`

Comment: @PieterGeerkens By accident.  That does not work for 289 instead of 291.

Comment: @MarnixKlooster: 289 mod 4 - 118 mod 4 =~ (1 - 2) mod 4 =~ -1 mod 4 =~ **3 mod 4**.

Comment: @MarnixKlooster: (289 - 118) mod 4 =~ 171 mod 4 =~ **3 mod 4**

Comment: @PieterGeerkens All I meant was that $(289 \text{ mod } 4) - (118 \text{ mod } 4) = -1 \not= 3$.  And of course you are right that $(289 \text{ mod } 4) - (118 \text{ mod } 4) \stackrel{\text{mod } 4}{=} 3$.)  You wrote "identically equals" but apparently meant equality modulo 4 (=~).  Oh, and I don't smoke. :-)

Answer (score 3):

We may as well subtract first, and then compute the difference, mod $4$: $\quad291 - 118 = 173$, so

$$ (291 - 118) \pmod 4 = 173 \pmod 4$$

Now, can you figure out what the remainder is when you divide $173$ by $4$?  That is:

What you need to find is the remainder $r$ of ${173}\div {4}$, where $ 0 \leq r \lt 4$.

Note that we can represent $173$ by using the division algorithm:$$173 = 4 \times 43 + r,\;$$ where $43$ is the *quotient*, and *r* is the *remainder* with value $0 \leq r \lt 4$. We just solve for $\,r,\,$ knowing $$173 = 4 \times 43 + r = 172 + r \implies r = 1$$

So $$ (291 - 118) \pmod 4 = 173 \pmod 4 = 1 \pmod 4$$

Another way to write this is $$ (291 - 118) = 173 \equiv 1 \pmod 4$$